# Determine Soap Action Name for The Default Namespace tempuri.org?

Tags: android, web-services

I am using the soap based wbeservice in my android app it is a login page but showing default namespace tempuri.org and there is not Soap Action mentioned in the WSDL file so what should i used as the soap action the webservice is online with the domain not on localhost.

This is my WebService code:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class WebService {

// Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
// private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
// Webservice URL - WSDL File location
// private static String URL = "http://namastii.co.in/Service.asmx";
// SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
// private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetUserDetails";


     private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.namastii.co.in/Service.asmx?op=GetUserDetails";

private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "GetUserDetails";

private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://namastii.co.in/";

private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://namastii.co.in/Service.asmx";

public static boolean invokeLoginWS(String username, String passWD,
        String webMethName) {



    boolean loginStatus = false;
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo userName = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo password = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Username
    userName.setName("username");
    // Set Value
    userName.setValue(username);
    // Set dataType
    userName.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(userName);
    // Set Password
    password.setName("password");
    // Set dataType
    password.setValue(passWD);
    // Set dataType
    password.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(password);
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

    try {
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + OPERATION_NAME, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to boolean variable variable
        loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        CheckDNLoginActivity.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return booleam to calling object
    return loginStatus;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the default is,     **`SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_NAMESPACE + SOAP_METHOD`**

So, just append the SOAP method name to the SOAP namespace.

For your webservice,

```
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetUserDetails";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "GetUserDetails";

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://www.namastii.co.in/Service.asmx";
```

Comment: On the Webservice the SAOP Namespace is showing tempuri.org and My method name is GetDetail but after giving this SOAP Action name nothing is happening.

Comment: Try SOAP action as `tempuri.org/GetDetail`

Comment: its a online webservice and as you said i try tempuri.org/GetDetail thousand time but nothing happens

Comment: Could you give me the link to the service?

Comment: here is the link sir,   http://www.namastii.co.in/Service.asmx its a login webservice but i am not able to use it in android if  u can help me then look at it default username is sushanta and passwd is 123

Comment: I hope you are using the ksoap2 library for Android.

Comment: And do you get any error/response from the server on the Android device? Or are you not able to connect at all due to incorrect action
?

Comment: Updated my answer with the correct identifiers to be used. If these are not working, then there is something else that is wrong. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Still Error ouccered invoking web service

Comment: could you catch the exception and do e.toString() and show me the complete error message ?

Comment: here is link [link](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Answers/EntryVersion.aspx?aid=805650&av=1191684)

Comment: Just give me the **complete** stack trace / error you get.

Comment: i get this error when click on the Login Button in the Log Cat 08-11 18:13:36.994: W/System.err(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 18:13:37.244: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3402 objects / 466016 bytes in 245ms
08-11 18:14:19.214: W/KeyCharacterMap(333): No keyboard for id 0
08-11 18:14:19.214: W/KeyCharacterMap(333): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin